# undefined reference to `cnss_get_platform_cap'

Tags: android, c, linux-kernel, kernel

I am compiling Android Kernel 3.18. 
I am getting this error

```
drivers/built-in.o: In function `enable_extldo':
/home/vinay/customKernel/3.18/kernel_yu_msm8937/drivers/bluetooth/bluetooth-power.c:307: undefined reference to `cnss_get_platform_cap'
/home/vinay/customKernel/3.18/kernel_yu_msm8937/drivers/bluetooth/bluetooth-power.c:307:(.text+0x5c45bc): relocation truncated to fit: R_AARCH64_CALL26 against undefined symbol `cnss_get_platform_cap'
Makefile:951: recipe for target 'vmlinux' failed
make: *** [vmlinux] Error 1
```

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/androidhut/kernel_yu_msm8937)
I am using **aarch64-linux-android-4.9** toolchain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem when I tried to compile a kernel for a MI device.

First you can see the function `cnss_get_platform_cap` was declared in `cnss.h` which is located in include/net:

[image]

And you open this file you will find this function was declared as a extern one:

[image]

So it is only a declaration here, not a implement.

Then we have a dig where the function is, I used find command to find all cnss related driver files and I find this function was implemented in `./net/wireless/cnss/cnss_pci.c`

[image]

As we can see, the function was here  and it will be a exported symbol after compiling.

[image]

And you can log your compile process and you will find actually succeed to compile `bluetooth-power.c`

[image]

Just when the makefile link vmlinux it will be a problem. So here we are. I searched the log and I didn't find  `cnss_pci.c` was ever compiled, only `cnss_common.c` was compiled, let's open the sub-makefile in net/wireless/cnss/

[image]

You will find you need to add a item in your defconfig file to compile `cnss_pci.c` which is `'CONFIG_CNSS_PCI=y'`. I add it to my defconfig file in `arch/arm64/configs/xxx_defconfig` and I solved this.

I just tried to merge a vendor patch into a newer CAF kernel, and there are many many syntax errors  even with auto merge.
As for the logic error and bugs, I don't know. A lot of things need to learn.
Hope you find your way out.

Comment: thanks a lot sir, it worked, and thanks for explaining so well.

Comment: I think this happened to be because I was using a lineage-15.1 kernel with a cm-14.1 kernel config.